# Sign as guest with Cognito and React native

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

I need to sign in as a guest in React Native but I don't find any documentation for this.
For some reason the documentation of AWS disabled React Native. I wonder what this means.
Chatgpt solutions like using empty username and password don't work.

Does anybody knows how to sign in as a guest? My cognito pool already allows unauthenticated logins, but can't figure out how to login. I've done it in other apps with username and password, but never tried this way.

My last option would be to create accounts with random data, but that's more like a hack than a solution.

https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/auth/guest-access/q/platform/react-native/ says:

```
React Native is not supported on this page. Please select one of the following:
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Looking for this myself.